# Showing global spinner during data fetching

Tags: react-query

I have components tree like:

```
<App>
   <Loader show={...}/>
   <Form>
      <input name="val" />
      <input type="submit" />
   </Form>
   <Data input={...}>
      Data is {here is data fetched for props.input}
   </Data>
</App>
```

I'm using hook `useQuery` from `react-query` in my `Data` component to fetch data for input and it works, but i have access to `isLoading` property within `Data` component and i want to have one global spinner which would be showed during any data request. Is it possible to do it using `react-query` ?

I thought about wrap `App` in `Suspense` and set `Loader` as fallback and enable `suspense` in `useQuery` call, but maybe there is any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

next to `isLoading`, `useQuery` also returns an `isFetching` Boolean, which will be true whenever a request is „in flight“ for the query, including background updates (`isLoading` will only be true for the „initial“ loading when you have no data yet).

If you want a global loading spinner, there is also the `useIsFetching` hook, which will return the amount of queries that are currently fetching. See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useIsFetching

Comment: useIsFetching is definitely what i needed thank you

Comment: although this answers the original intent, how about a global `isLoading` check? There does not seem to be an `useIsLoading` hook

Comment: there is not, but it can be done in userland by using the useIsFetching hook with a custom predicate filter: useIsFetching({ predicate: query => query.state === 'loading'}). or, you can just use suspense which does this as well :)

Comment: I always wonder if having a global loading state has good performance considering that all connected components will receive an update when the loading state changes and probably there are many connected components (either with Redux or Context API). So I wonder what would be the best approach without using useQuery (which I love but we do not have it yet).