# Global loader for react-query only after the initial fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-query

How can I add a global loader, but it should not be shown on the initial fetch? I have a different page-wide loader for the initial fetch.

I did see [this](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/background-fetching-indicators#displaying-global-background-fetching-loading-state), using `useIsFetching`. But it seems like `isFetching` is `true` for the initial fetch as well. And there doesn't seem to be a `useIsLoading` equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution as I was typing the question from the comment by [TkDodo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8405310/tkdodo) under this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65521597/9549012). But seems like it's outdated, so I opted to write a proper answer. This is what I ended up using.

```
export function LoadingIndicator() {
  const isFetching = useIsFetching({
    predicate: (query) => query.state.status !== "loading",
  });

  return isFetching ? (
    <div className="fixed z-[9999] bg-white bottom-5 right-5 w-fit shadow-md rounded-md px-4 py-2 flex gap-2 items-center">
      <Loader size="xs" />
      <span>Updating data...</span>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

There are [other filters](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/filters#query-filters) available as well.